# Force home to index.asp with URL rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm running a split test which requires my home page to **ONLY** be accessible at **/index.asp** (temporarily) so it can be correctly redirected to **/index2.asp**

How can I set up a rewrite rule to force **ONLY** these two URLs to route to http://www.domain.com/index.asp , without affecting other pages and sub-folders etc ??

http://www.domain.com (blank)

http://www.domain.com/ (with trailing slash)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.asp [L]
```

Pattern `^/?$` will only match `http://www.domain.com` OR `http://www.domain.com/`